# Extract city from the address column

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqSfr.jpg)What happens if if ship 3 and 4 are null, but ship2 is not null, that should be city state

Here is sample data in the picture.

Comment: There are lots of examples of getting substrings using `substr` and `instr`, or regular expressions. What have you tried so far and what problems did you have?

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: Can anyone help me with above question?

Comment: You have not asked a question. You posted an image and made a statement. What question do you want to have answered?

Comment: What happens if if ship 3 and 4 are null, but ship2 is not null, in this case city should be from ship 2

Comment: Its vice versa...i am trying use this to extract in another query!! is there a way i can figure out?

Comment: Please don't change the question substantially after it has been answered, it invalidates the effort people have already put into helping you. If you have a follow-on question then ask a *new* question, referring back to this one if relevant. Also, [please post formatted text ratherthan images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the oldfashioned `SUBSTR + INSTR` combination which, if compared to Gordon's and Barbaros' suggestions, seems to be somewhat better as their queries return strings that don't even contain a comma, while the OP says

> extract city from 1 letter until 1 comma

Here's a comparison:

```
SQL> with tab (addr) as
  2  (
  3    select 'RALEIGH, NC 27604-3229'  from dual union all
  4    select 'SUITE A' from dual union all
  5    select 'COEUR D ALENE, ID 83815-8652' from dual union all
  6    select '*O/S CITY LIMITS*' from dual
  7  )
  8  select addr,
  9    substr(addr, 1, instr(addr, ',') - 1) littlefoot,
 10    --
 11    regexp_substr(addr, '[^,]+', 1, 1) gordon,
 12    regexp_substr(addr,'[^,]+') barbaros
 13  from tab;

ADDR                         LITTLEFOOT      GORDON               BARBAROS
---------------------------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
RALEIGH, NC 27604-3229       RALEIGH         RALEIGH              RALEIGH
SUITE A                                      SUITE A              SUITE A
COEUR D ALENE, ID 83815-8652 COEUR D ALENE   COEUR D ALENE        COEUR D ALENE
*O/S CITY LIMITS*                            *O/S CITY LIMITS*    *O/S CITY LIMITS*

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the part before the first comma, you can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(addr, '[^,]+', 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `regexp_substr` with `[^,]+` pattern as below

```
select regexp_substr(address,'[^,]+') as city
  from tab;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo 1*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ab5b30/434)

Or alternatively by creating an auxilary table :

```
with tab as
(
select 'RALEIGH, NC 27604-3229' as str from dual union all
select 'SALINAS, CA 93901' from dual union all
select 'DEPEW, NY 14043-2603' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+') as city
  from tab;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo 2*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ab5b30/438)

Comment: @RaviLess excuse me but that's another question and should be asked as a seperate question but not as a comment , especially unformatted as this ..

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: @RaviLess no, not important :)

Comment: Can u help me with this new question

Comment: @RaviLess sorry but it's problem to reach the site `imgur` in my country to see the images. I could overtake this problem with the help of my VPN, but my connection is not suitable for using that VPN at the place where I stay now :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regexp, you can just use:

```
select substr(city,1,(instr(city,',')-1))
  from mytable;
```